# Querying CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following JSON stored in my CosmosDB:

```
{
   "id": "zzzzzzz",
   "organizationId": "xxxxxxxx",
   "agentId": "yyyyyyyyyyy",
   "createdAt": "2023-05-03T16:46:53.77Z",
   "createdAtUtc": "2023-05-03T07:16:53.78Z",
   "content": {
    "modelAt": "2023-05-03T16:46:53.77Z",
    "modelAtUtc": "2023-05-03T07:16:53.78Z",
    "machineId": "99999",
    "driverId": "777",
    "operatorId": "88",
    "collectedDate": "Wednesday, 3 May 2023",
    "totalCount": 18.9,
    "sequenceNumber": 1000024,
    "totalQuantity": 0,
    "values": {
        "created": "2023-05-02T14:59:15Z",
        "version": "1.28.1588",
        "serialNumber": "4087",
        "site": "Site",
        "installationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "setup": {
            "file": "xxxx.ini",
            "name": "xxxx",
            "encoding": "Windows-1252",
            "decimals": 2,
            "model": {
                "sequenceNumber": 1000024,
                "startTime": "2023-05-02T14:59:03Z",
                "endTime": "2023-05-02T14:59:13Z",
                "total": 18.9,
                "expectedTotal": 0,
                "identities": [{
                        "name": "Box",
                        "value": 123,
                        "inHierarchy": "yes"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Area",
                        "value": 8,
                        "inHierarchy": "yes"
                    }
                ],
                "types": {
                    "reject": "1",
                    "total": 0.4,
                    "type": [{
                            "mediaType": "type",
                            "name": "Reject",
                            "label": "R",
                            "value": 0,
                            "count": 1,
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "mediaType": "type",
                            "name": "1$",
                            "label": "",
                            "value": 100,
                            "count": 0,
                            "total": 123
                        },
                        {
                            "mediaType": "type",
                            "name": "50c",
                            "label": "",
                            "value": 50,
                            "count": 5,
                            "total": 5234
                        },
                        {
                            "mediaType": "type",
                            "name": "20c",
                            "label": "",
                            "value": 20,
                            "count": 2,
                            "total": 2656
                        },
                        {
                            "mediaType": "type",
                            "name": "10c",
                            "label": "",
                            "value": 10,
                            "count": 0,
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "mediaType": "type",
                            "name": "5c",
                            "label": "",
                            "value": 5,
                            "count": 0,
                            "total": 234
                        },
                        {
                            "mediaType": "type",
                            "name": "1$",
                            "label": "o",
                            "value": 100,
                            "count": 0,
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "mediaType": "type",
                            "name": "50c",
                            "label": "o",
                            "value": 50,
                            "count": 0,
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "mediaType": "type",
                            "name": "20c",
                            "label": "o",
                            "value": 20,
                            "count": 0,
                            "total": 876
                        },
                        {
                            "mediaType": "type",
                            "name": "10c",
                            "label": "o",
                            "value": 10,
                            "count": 4,
                            "total": 0.4
                        },
                        {
                            "mediaType": "type",
                            "name": "5c",
                            "label": "o",
                            "value": 5,
                            "count": 0,
                            "total": 867
                        },
                        {
                            "mediaType": "type",
                            "name": "1c",
                            "label": "o",
                            "value": 1,
                            "count": 0,
                            "total": 45
                        }
                    ]
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

How can I retrieve the values for 'value', 'count', and 'total' individually, specifically when the 'mediaType' is 'type'? Additionally, I would like to calculate the sum of 'total' when the 'label' is empty and the label is 'o'.

I have crafted these queries that are currently yielding the desired results:

```
SELECT SUM(coin.count) AS oldSeriesTotal
FROM c
JOIN coin IN c.content.values.setup.transaction.coins.coin
WHERE c.agentId = 'xxxx' AND coin.label = 'o'
GROUP BY c.content.values.setup.transaction.sequenceNumber
```

And

```
SELECT SUM(coin.count) AS oldSeriesTotal
FROM c
JOIN coin IN c.content.values.setup.transaction.coins.coin
WHERE c.agentId = 'xxxx' AND coin.label = ''
GROUP BY c.content.values.setup.transaction.sequenceNumber
```

However, I require these values to be retrieved in a single query. I attempted to accomplish this by constructing the following query, which is evidently incorrect:

```
SELECT 
c.content.machineId AS vendingMachineNumber, 
c.content.driverId AS driverNumber, 
c.content.collectedDate AS collectedDate, 
c.content.modelAt AS modelAt, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[1].count AS one, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[1].total AS oneTotal, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[1].name AS oneName, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[2].count AS fiftytnecs,
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[2].total AS fiftyTotal,
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[2].name AS fiftyName, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[3].count AS twentytnecs, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[3].total AS twentyTotal,
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[3].name AS twentyName, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[4].count AS tentnecs, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[4].total AS tenTotal,
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[4].name AS tenName, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[5].count AS fivetnecs, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[5].total AS fiveTotal, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[5].name AS fiveName,
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[6].count AS oneOld, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[6].total AS oneTotalOld, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[6].name AS oneNameOld,
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[7].count AS fiftytnecsOld,
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[7].total AS fiftyTotalOld,
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[7].name AS fiftyNameOld, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[8].count AS twentytnecsOld, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[8].total AS twentyTotalOld,
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[8].name AS twentyNameOld, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[9].count AS tentnecsOld, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[9].total AS tenTotalOld,
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[9].name AS tenNameOld, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[10].count AS fivetnecsOld, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[10].total AS fiveTotalOld, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[10].name AS fiveNameOld, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[11].count AS onetnecOld, 
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[11].total AS onetnecTotalOld,
c.content.values.setup.model.types.type[11].name AS onetnecNameOld
FROM 
c
WHERE c.agentId = 'xxxxx'
```

My objective is to consolidate and merge all of these queries into a single unified query.

Comment: You already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76285700/272109), and it was already closed, with comments under the question that this is not really a practical (or understandable) thing, with a suggestion to consider re-visiting your data model and the way you're retrieving data, along with the fact that you're traversing data as an ordered array. Please don't repost an identical question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon What's not clear, my friend?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have added the sample data, the queries I created and what I have tried to do. I think it is very clear what I am looking for. If you can't understand, please move on and do not '-1' my question. But if its still unclear what I want I will try one more time: I need a query that selects the values of 'count', 'total', and 'value', and adds each value to a variable while summing the 'total' field where the label is empty and where the label is 'o', in different variables.

Comment: You've had two people, both product experts, tell you that what you're asking for is not something that has a clear answer, and that is significantly complex (plus you've modeled your data, and your resultant query, in ways that don't really make sense for a document store). The downvote is because you repeated your question after deleting it, after getting real world feedback. You can't just post an identical answer, getting rid of original comments, when the original (and repost) are both overly broad, with no clear-cut way to provide what you're asking for.

Comment: Further: You don't have an error or issue; you solved it, but you want something better, and you've left it to the Community to come up with a solution for you. And that's not how this site works.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yes that's why I ask here, because I need a solution, I am not an expert in queries/CosmosDB and this is been blocking me for the past week and I can't go further. Trust me: This is the last place I want to come to ask help because this place is full of arrogant people that they think they are special because they know more. I have no pleasure to create a post here.

Comment: Please share valid JSON Item so that we can reproduce.

Comment: @ShaktiSingh-MSFT JSON file on the body of the topic, had a small mistake and now its valid. Thanks

Comment: In the queries, transaction is mentioned which is not present in the Input JSON. Please share expected result json.